# message_filters-related issue

Tags: boost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was following a tutorial on [message_filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters) in order to subscribe to 2 different topics of different type and later use it in a callback function. However, I got a weird long error message as follow:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/publisher.h:35,
                 from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/node_handle.h:32,
                 from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/include/ros/ros.h:45,
                 from /home/shah/code/ros_workspace/point_cloud_drone/src/pointcloud_builder_node.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp: In member function ‘void boost::_bi::list3<A1, A2, A3>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, A = boost::_bi::list9<const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&>, A1 = boost::arg<1>, A2 = boost::arg<2>, A3 = boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*>]’:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:305:   instantiated from ‘typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(const A1&, const A2&, const A3&, const A4&, const A5&, const A6&, const A7&, const A8&, const A9&) [with A1 = boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, A2 = boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, A3 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A4 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A5 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A6 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A7 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A8 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A9 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, R = void, F = boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, L = boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> >]’
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:820:   instantiated from ‘void boost::_bi::list9<A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> > >, A = boost::_bi::list9<const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&>, A1 = boost::arg<1>, A2 = boost::arg<2>, A3 = boost::arg<3>, A4 = boost::arg<4>, A5 = boost::arg<5>, A6 = boost::arg<6>, A7 = boost::arg<7>, A8 = boost::arg<8>, A9 = boost::arg<9>]’
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:305:   instantiated from ‘typename boost::_bi::result_traits<R, F>::type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(const A1&, const A2&, const A3&, const A4&, const A5&, const A6&, const A7&, const A8&, const A9&) [with A1 = boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, A2 = boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, A3 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A4 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A5 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A6 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A7 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A8 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, A9 = boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>, R = boost::_bi::unspecified, F = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> > >, L = boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> >]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153:   instantiated from ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker9<FunctionObj, R, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8) [with FunctionObj = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >, R = void, T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&, T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >&, T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:913:   instantiated from ‘void boost::function9<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >, R = void, T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&, T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >&, T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:722:   instantiated from ‘boost::function9<R, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9>::function9(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >, R = void, T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&, T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >&, T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1064:   instantiated from ‘boost::function<R(T0, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not::value, int>::type) [with Functor = boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> > >, boost::_bi::list9<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::arg<3>, boost::arg<4>, boost::arg<5>, boost::arg<6>, boost::arg<7>, boost::arg<8>, boost::arg<9> > >, R = void, T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&, T1 = const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >&, T2 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T3 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T4 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T5 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T6 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T7 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&, T8 = const boost::shared_ptr<const message_filters::NullType>&]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/signal9.h:281:   instantiated from ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::Signal9<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::addCallback(C&) [with C = const boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> > >, M0 = geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:310:   instantiated from ‘message_filters::Connection message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::registerCallback(const C&) [with C = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<PointCloudBuilder*> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/home/shah/code/ros_workspace/point_cloud_drone/src/pointcloud_builder_node.cpp:137:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:385: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf2<void, PointCloudBuilder, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >&, const boost::shared_ptr<const geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >&, PointCloudBuilder*&)’
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:272: note: candidates are: R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(T*, A1, A2) const [with R = void, T = PointCloudBuilder, A1 = const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, A2 = const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&]
/usr/include/boost/bind/mem_fn_template.hpp:291: note:                 R boost::_mfi::mf2<R, T, A1, A2>::operator()(T&, A1, A2) const [with R = void, T = PointCloudBuilder, A1 = const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr&, A2 = const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr&]
In file included from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/time_synchronizer.h:39,
                 from /home/shah/code/ros_workspace/point_cloud_drone/src/pointcloud_builder_node.cpp:20:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/sync_policies/exact_time.h: In member function ‘void message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::add(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename message_filters::PolicyBase<M0, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6, M7, M8>::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 1, M0 = geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, M1 = geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, M2 = message_filters::NullType, M3 = message_filters::NullType, M4 = message_filters::NullType, M5 = message_filters::NullType, M6 = message_filters::NullType, M7 = message_filters::NullType, M8 = message_filters::NullType]’:
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:358:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::cb(const typename boost::mpl::at_c<typename Policy::Events, i>::type&) [with int i = 1, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:291:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&, F8&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F8 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:282:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&, F7&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F7 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:275:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&, F6&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F6 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:268:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&, F5&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F5 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:261:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&, F4&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F4 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:254:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&, F3&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, F3 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:247:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&, F2&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, F2 = message_filters::NullFilter<message_filters::NullType>, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
/opt/ros/electric/stacks/ros_comm/utilities/message_filters/include/message_filters/synchronizer.h:240:   instantiated from ‘void message_filters::Synchronizer<Policy>::connectInput(F0&, F1&) [with F0 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> > >, F1 = message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> > >, Policy = message_filters::sync_policies::ExactTime<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped_<std::allocator<void> >, geometry_msgs::Pose2D_<std::allocator<void> >, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType, message_filters::NullType>]’
```

My code snippet is like this:

```
    message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> poseLD_sub(n, "pose3D_LD", 1);
    message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::Pose2D> pose2D_sub(n, "pose2D", 1);
    TimeSynchronizer<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped, geometry_msgs::Pose2D> sync(poseLD_sub, pose2D_sub, 10);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&PointCloudBuilder::callback, _1, _2, this));
```

And here is the callback function:

```
void PointCloudBuilder::callback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr& poseLD_ptr, const geometry_msgs::Pose2DConstPtr& pose2D_ptr)
{
    ROS_INFO("Here, I will process something on the arrived values");
}
```

Could someone check the parameter values that I filled, possibly wrong somewhere. From the error message, it could also be something to do with *boost*. What could go wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12439/message_filters-related-issue/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but maybe the `this` should be the 2nd and not the last parameter to `bind`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-12-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-01-07**:
I'm now not getting any compile error, but, it seems that it doesn't enter the callback function, as I try to "ROS_INFO" in the function and look the output in rxconsole.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-27**:
I got your point. The only thing I need is that running an image publisher, which I don't have, or something on the net related, that I can easily use it.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-27**:
You modified more and built that into your program. If you solely use the sample program everything should be alright there and you can check if it works with your data.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-26**:
What do you mean by "edit the sample code with your message types"? I've used the sample code with my message types already as shown in the above code snippet, or I misunderstood something?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-26**:
First, you might try to simple edit the sample code with your message types to confirm the callback is called. There is one thing to note: AFAIK the Timesynchronizer needs exact timestamp matches, not approximate ones.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-12-25**:
Yes, I think you're right too, I've put *this* pointer the second argument, but, it's still not working.